# Problema al imprimir dato de array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un problema en el siguiente código, estoy intentando imprimir el dato 'notas' del array con 'foreach' pero al imprimir con 'echo' me imprime la palabra 'Array' y no me imprime los datos que quiero.

```
$persona1 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre1',
   'notas' => [1,2,3,4]
];

$persona2 = [
   'nombre' => 'nombre2',
   'notas' => [5,6,7,8]
];


$datos=[$persona1, $persona2];



foreach($datos as $personas){

    echo $personas['nombre'] . " " . $personas['notas'] . " , ";
}

// Me imprime este resultado: nombre1 Array , nombre2 Array
// Como quiero que lo imprima : nombre1 1,2,3,4 , nombre2 5,6,7,8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo estás teniendo porque estás tratando de imprimir en pantalla `$personas['$notas']` y se trata de un **array**.

Para poder acceder a las diferentes notas de la "persona" tienes que montar otro `foreach` dentro de tu `foreach` para recorrer dicho **array**.

**PHP**

```
foreach($datos as $personas){
    echo ($personas['nombre']);
    foreach($personas['notas'] as $nota){
        echo (' '. $nota . ' ');    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Te imprime *array* porque lo que hay en `notas` es un array. Los elementos de un array no puedes imprimirlos con `echo`, debes recorrerlos usando un bucle: `for, while`, etc, o usar alguna función de ayuda adecuada a lo que necesitas.

Dado que quieres mostrar las notas separadas por comas, puedes usar [**`implode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php). Esta función sirve para mostrar los elementos de un array separados por el o los caracteres que indiques en su primer parámetro.

Por ejemplo, al hacer `implode(",",$personas['notas'])`, te mostrará algo como esto: `1,2,3,4`. O sea, extraerá cada valor del array y lo separará por `,`, dado que pusiste una coma como primer parámetro en la función.

Puedes por tanto escribir tu código así:

```
foreach($datos as $personas){
    echo $personas['nombre'] . " " . implode(",",$personas['notas']).PHP_EOL;
}
```

`PHP_EOL` es equivalente al salto de línea, para que separe cada elemento del array con un espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Se imprime array porque efectivamente es un array y para imprimir sus elementos este se debe recorrer o utilizar alguna función para arrays que te facilite el trabajo. Ej:

```
echo implode( “,”, $personas[“notas”] );
```

La función implode une los elementos de un array en un string concatenado con el caracter que indiques.